# What if we put zero at the place of negative index in a string?

Tags: python, arrays, string, indexing

```py
name = "Deepesh"

print(name[0:0]) # this does not print anything
```

Q1. Why the above statement is not printing anything

```py
print(name[-5:0]) # this also does not print anything
```

Q2. Why the given statement is not printing the value present from index -5 to -1?

Thanks for reading!

I have tried all the patterns similar to this kind of statements. I have got a point that what will be the output, but why this kind of output is coming? Actually, I want to know that how the compiler reads this kind of statements.

For example:

```
name[a : b : c]
```

In this compiler will read which of the parameter first? a, b or c?

Comment: `name[0:0]` is asking for "give me the characters between the beginning of the string and the beginning of the string". So the result is an empty string (`0:1` would yield `"D"`, so intuitively, `0:0` should be `""`).  `name[-5:0]` means "give me the characters starting at position 2 ( = 7-5 ) and ending at position `0` (ie: `name[2:0]`). There aren't any characters that fit that definition because your range is backwards.

Comment: Essentially, slicing is the same as taking an intersection of subsets. `name[x:y]` is the intersection of the two sets: `1. elements in name with an index greater than or equal to x`, and `2. elements in name with an index strictly less than y`.

Answer (score 0):

The first reason why it cannot be printed is that the slice is a left-closed-right intercept, that is, the right index is not included, so the result of [0:0] is the element that does not contain index 0.
The second slicing method is because the default way of slicing is to start slicing from left to right, [-5:0] means the same as [-5:0:1], that is, the starting position is at -5 and the ending position is at 0, but the interception order of the step is from left to right, obviously the opposite of the starting and ending positions, because there will not be any results, at this time, just need to change the direction of the step to be consistent with the interception of the starting and ending reverse that is, [-5:0:-1]

The specific code is as follows:

```
 name = "Deepesh"
 print(name[-5:0:-1])
 outinfo: ee
```